# PostgreSQL GOTO bak in function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have function like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION task_manager(task integer, params text)
   RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
IF task = 1 THEN
  <<lab1>>
  -- some work 1
ELSIF task = 2 THEN
  -- some work 2

  -- need to exec 'some work 1'
  GOTO lab1;
END IF;

RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

GOTO not workking due GOTO syntax.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Isolate `work1` into a function in its own?

Comment: There is no `goto` in PL/pgSQL. What part of the manual made you think there is one? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you right you always need to do "work1", and if task = 2 then do work2 first.

So you can do work 1 every time..

[EDIT] based on your comment; try using multiple IF statements instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION task_manager(task integer, params text)
   RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
IF task = 1 OR task = 2 THEN

  -- some work 1


END IF;

  IF task = 2 THEN

  -- some work 2


END IF;

RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Logic is - function execute only one task by number, 1 , 2, or any other. For some tasks, not for all, need execute another task. Possible isolate tasks per function, but not convenient coz task is small but there are many.